# Cannot open navigationbar

Tags: android, navigation

I click the FloatingActionButton to open my navigation menu, But not working

```
DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START);
        }
    });
```

No errors in my logcat.
Any one help.

Comment: isDrawerOpen check is the drawer open .. use openDrawer(GravitiyCompat.START)

Comment: I get a error.It is not boolen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `isDrawerOpen` method checks if drawer open or not , its not doing anything only checks. You can use this in `onClick` method:

```
if(drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
    closeNavDrawer();
}else {
    drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
}
```

`closeNavDrawer` method:

```
protected void closeNavDrawer() {
    if (drawer != null) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }
}
```